# Map JSON POSTed in Java Spring Rest Controller to POJO

Tags: java, json, spring

I am sending the following JSON object to my Java Spring application

```
{
    "ewsUrl":"https://dummy.url.com",
    "ewsIdentityToken":"12345",
    "itemIds":["itemids"],
    "entityId":null,
    "documentType":"Dummy",
    "documentStatus":"Record",
    "filename":"message.eml",
    "metadata":{"title":"message"}
}
```

I have defined an object `public class RequestObject` and in my controller I have

```
  public RequestObject 
    testMyStuff(@CurrentUser User currentUser, 
    @RequestBody RequestObject myDummyObject) throws Exception {
       return myDummyObject
    }
```

My application returns the error `Could not read document: Root name 'ewsUrl' does not match expected ('RequestObject') for type...etc`

However if I send the JSON formatted like this it successfully maps the object:

```
{ "RequestObject":
    {
        "ewsUrl":"https://dummy.url.com",
        "ewsIdentityToken":"12345",
        "itemIds":["itemids"],
        "entityId":null,
        "documentType":"Dummy",
        "documentStatus":"Record",
        "filename":"message.eml",
        "metadata":{"title":"message"}
    }
}
```

I do not want to name the object in my JSON, I want to send as described in the first example. How do I achieve this?

UPDATE:

RequestObject.java

```
public class RequestObject {

    public String ewsUrl;
    public String ewsIdentityToken;
    public String[] itemIds;
    public String entityId;
    public String documentType;
    public String documentStatus;
    public String filename;
    public Metadata metadata;

    public RequestObject() {
    }

    public static class Metadata {
        public String title;
    }
}
```

UPDATE2:

The way it is described in [this example](http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program) suggests that the object does not need to be named in the JSON data in the POST request. I think I am emulating this example, but I'm getting different results. 
Is there a configuration for Jackson/Spring that I am missing?

Update 3:

The complete error message is:

```
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
Could not read document: 
Root name 'ewsUrl' does not match expected ('RequestObject') for type 
[simple type, class uk.co.test.RequestObject] at [Source: 
java.io.PushbackInputStream@7e223182; line: 2, column: 9]; 
nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 
Root name 'ewsUrl' does not match expected ('RequestObject') for type 
[simple type, class uk.co.test.RequestObject]
```

Comment: Can you paste the code for the `RequestObject` class?

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond updated.

Comment: Have you tried declaring the `Metadata` class in a separate file? I'm asking because the behavior you are experiencing is not expected. Also, there are no getters and setters in your `RequestObject`?

Comment: The metadata class is not a problem. Also, the absence of getters and setters isn't an issue. I could reduce the problem to a single value in the RequestObject and the problem remains the same.

Comment: Okay, replicated your code and for me it works normally. I suspect it has something to do with Jackson. Do you have any configuration?

Comment: @NielsMasdorp I think that's the issue. I had assumed that because the Object was getting mapped, and that the error included something about jackson, that it was installed, but I'm just adding it to the Gradle file now to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @NielsMasdorp This is the complete error message: `Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Root name 'ewsUrl' does not match expected ('RequestObject') for type [simple type, class uk.co.test.RequestObject]
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@7e223182; line: 2, column: 9]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Root name 'ewsUrl' does not match expected ('RequestObject') for type [simple type, class uk.co.test.RequestObject]`

Comment: @NielsMasdorp How do I tell if I am using the correct Converters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some configuration settings that look like they can be defined for the ObjectMapper that controls the behaviour of the root element:

- https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE - see SerializationFeature.html#WRAP_ROOT_VALUE as well.

UNWRAP_ROOT_MODULE is disabled by default according to the docs so not sure why you're seeing the behaviour you are.

Config example for spring is available at 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/JacksonObjectMapperFactoryBean.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject`

**Update**

You can get your Json Object via `JSONArray.getJSONObject()`

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to give me a bit more than that.

Comment: i think you need a structure that depends on Key - Value pairs. You need your data to be seprated by commas. And this, exactly gives me the idea to define a JSONArray insert the Key - Value pairs as JSONObjects in it.

Comment: `@RequestBody RequestObject myDummyObject` is the code in question - How do you suggest I apply it to that?

Comment: It seems like your RequestBody is fine. On the other hand, do you have JacksonMessageconverter in your configuration file? 
<property name="messageConverters">
<list>
<ref bean="jacksonMessageConverter"/>
</list>
</property>